# Flex и div overflow проблемы

Tags: css, flexbox

Почему у элемента `exampleblock` не появляется скроллбар? Если  допустим ему задать ширину 100%, то не работает.
Если например задать ширину для `container__content`, то работает. Но мне нужно сохранить адаптивность.

Почему так происходит? Если верстать не флексами, то всё нормально. Есть ли где-нибудь описание, почему так происходит?

Вот пример моей вёрстки: https://codepen.io/verng/pen/zJQrxY

Comment: Нужно добавить `min-width: 0` блоку `.container__content`. Вот [статья на эту тему](https://habr.com/post/329820/).

Comment: @diraria Ну вот почему всё оказалось так просто.... пол дня мучался, не мог на гуглить. Спасибо, большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить к `.container__content` `overflow: auto;` и тоже будет работать